# Is there any possibility to **fix** a customized library with my own shapes to the sidebar on the left in draw.io/diagrams.net?

Tags: javascript, html, draw.io

I am tired up every time importing my custom shapes library to the draw.io/diagrams.net. I want to know is there any way that my custom library gets imported by default (like the default general library) every time I open draw.io/diagrams.net.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add URL parameter for custom library as described here: https://www.diagrams.net/doc/faq/supported-url-parameters

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your efforts. But I have to paste the URL in the clibs parameter every time I open draw.io to load the library. I want that once the I load the library it should stay forever (I don't have to load it every time I open draw.io).